# Get List of possible elements expected on a node

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk, presentation

I'm getting below error on validation my XML:
"The element has unexpected child element 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main:p'. List of possible elements expected: http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main:bodyPr."

Where can I find all the possible and required properties for a element node.

Comment: Was your question answered or do you need more help?

Comment: Thanks Thomas , EndParagraph property was missing on my paragraph node. After adding it the issue resolved.

Comment: If my answer helped, please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/. You can search for the desired Open XML element, e.g., [w:p](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_p-1.html), [w:r](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_r-2.html), or [w:pPr](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_pPr-2.html).

Another source with additional information is https://c-rex.net/projects/samples/ooxml/e1/index.html. I'm not listing the standard, because that's a document with more than 5.000 pages ...